# Convert a fillable PDF form (containing javascript) to HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, converters

Sorry in advance! I am very new to the subject
I have created a fillable form using adobe acrobat that includes a drop-down that, depending on what is selected, changes some text in a text field later in the document (where I used javascript in the validation field of the dropdown). I want to convert this to an HTML form where this background process for the drop-down & text fields is kept (when using the adobe create web form option, it won't let me keep the background script for the dropdown).
I have tried a few different converters but none have kept the javascript
Is this easily doable for someone with very basic knowledge? Any help is appreciated.